# Can I find where a PHP anonymous function was defined?

Tags: php, reflection, closures, anonymous-function

Closures don't seem to be fully exposed to reflection. On inspection as an object, it doesn't seem to have anything useful:

```
$foo = function ($a, $b) {};
$ref = new ReflectionObject($foo);
var_dump($ref->getFileName()); // false
```

You can get parameters of the anonymous function:

```
$invoker = $ref->getMethod('__invoke');
var_dump($invoker->getParameters()); // "a" and "b"!
```

But not where it was defined:

```
var_dump($invoker->getFileName()); // false
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `ReflectionFunction` instead of `ReflectionObject`.

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) is the reference.
It even includes an `isClosure` method, and accepts a closure as a constructor argument. :-)

Example:

```
$callback = function (){ echo 'hello'; };
$r = new ReflectionFunction($callback);
$startLine = $r->getStartLine();
$file = $r->getFileName();
$is_closure = $r->isClosure();
```

Comment: Thanks. I only partially read the docs and assumed that the "name" parameter required a string.

Comment: (for future visitors) I updated my answer to call out that it can take a closure for a `__construct()` argument.